# What can a government agency see if they control Tor nodes?

Tags: anonymity, tor

If I use Tails/tor on public WiFi, and a government agency is controlling /snooping nodes or uses malware to conduct a waterhole attack, what information can they gather about me?

Comment: They could compromise your device and install malware at the firmware level, recording everything you do if you fell for a watering hole attack. If you're worried about NSA level attackers, lets just say the outlook is not good, especially if youre asking on stack exchange about it.

Comment: Well I haven't been compromised yet and this profile is set up using protonmail (which was set up under a vpn) and being accessed via tor.... but i get your point.can a waterhole attack happen if im using tor and have https everywhere plus no script enabled? And they can install malware at a firmware level if im using tails on a bootable usb and there a no harddrive in the computer?

Comment: Yes its 100% possible that there is an 0 day in tor browser, in fact one with maximum noscript settings enabled will go for 2,000,000 dollars from zerodium. There is a huge demand especially from nation groups so it is unthinkable to me that there isnt a currently used exploit available to them.

Comment: Wow that's crazy!  Had no idea! Then what sort of precautions can one take to keep their anonymity safe during a watering hole attack??

Comment: don't go to the watering hole

Comment: Well obviously, but any site could be a potential wattering hole right??

Comment: "Legitimate or popular websites of high-profile companies are usually the focus of watering hole attacks" https://www.techopedia.com/definition/31858/watering-hole-attack